# Cocos2d schedule only once

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How can I make cocos2d schedule selector only once? Right now the best I can do is:

```
[self schedule:@selector(eventHappend:) interval:2];
```

and `eventHappend:`

```
- (void)eventHappend: (ccTime) dt
{
    [self unschedule:@selector(eventHappend:)];
    // Do stuff
}
```

but that seems like a workaround... is there a method to schedule only once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run a sequence of actions on the node, a CCDelay followed by a CCCallFunc that invokes your method.

Like this...

```
[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2], 
                                    [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(eventHappened)],
                                    nil]];
```

Comment: This is great, thanks...

For correctness sake, I believe the class is CCDelayTime rather than CCDelay.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void) scheduleOnce: (SEL)selector delay: (ccTime)delay
```

Schedules a selector that runs only once, with a delay of 0 or larger

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#afe99d609f17c4c849e4543805ffeceab

Comment: Good answer, this is definitely the simplest. However, I hit one big limitation: you can't schedule the same selector more than once. "Duh," you say, "it's called `scheduleOnce`", but what I (and I think the OP) needed was a `scheduleNonRepeating`. In my case, I have a method that schedules _itself_ after a jittered delay to populate a layer with sprites up to a set capacity--so either because it's executing from a scheduled instance or because the delay is too short, it says: `CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000` and never fires.

Answer (score 0):

you also can use this:

```
[self unschedule:_cmd];
```

in your eventHappened Function - it will make your schedule run once.

Comment: _cmd is your current method

Answer (score -1):

Most of these are way too complicated for what you need (even though they are pretty simple)

All you need is the following line of code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(eventHappend:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

It will run your method eventHappend one time only.

Comment: Can't find this in the docs...what class does this method belong to? If it used to exist it may have been removed by v2.1.

Comment: Oh! I see, it's a method on `NSObject`, in the `NSDelayedPerforming` category... Okay, that's probably a very bad idea in the context of a cocos2d game, because Foundation framework's built-in timers won't respect the cocos2d game clock--e.g. if you pause the game, the selector will still fire!